# How to convert flv video to 3gp video?

Tags: video, flv, 3gp, video-conversion

How to convert .flv video format to .3gp for use on an Android device using a desktop computer?

Answer (score 3):

Download and install [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). The following command will encode to h.264 video with the baseline profile, as demanded by the Android media player.

To change the quality, change the `crf` parameter. Lower means better, and sane values are from 19 to 25 or more.

As audio, AAC is used with a bitrate of 192 kBit/s.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -crf 23 -c:a libfaac -b:a 192k out.3gp
```

Answer (score 2):

Will provided a link to ffmpeg - This is a good solution, but if you don't know or want to mess around with command prompt tools, I recommend that you take a look at [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a very capable, free, video converter.

Answer (score 0):

[Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) is an online conversion utility that can do this without installing software if you are looking for a way to do it from any box.

Answer (score 0):

[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) should be able to do it.  It has a number of presets for various mobile devices.